message.embeds from discord.py library cant see embed from SD.C Monitoring bot
Im trying to make discord bot with simple bump counter with leaderboard. When server is bumped - bot that makes connection with server monitoring sends an embed in chat which says that server is bumped. I use that to get discord user that bumped the server and calculate different stuff for him.
Everything works fine with Disboard, DSMonitoring, Server Monitoring, I also can get embed contents of other bots if i want. But message.embeds cant see embed of SD.C Monitoring and I cant understand why.
here is what gives message.embeds for SD.C Monitoring, although I can see on my test discord server that embed exists:
[]
here is an example of what gives message.embeds for any other message with embed:
[<discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x0000020B7AD017E0>]
Here is part of code that seems to contain everything relevant for this problem:your text
from typing import Final
import os
import json
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord import Intents, Client, Message
from responses import get_response
from dataStoring import StoreDataInJson
from commands import bot
load_dotenv()
TOKEN: Final[str] = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

intents: Intents = Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client: Client = Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready() -> None:
    print(f'{client.user} is now running')

@client.event
async def on_message(message: Message) -> None:
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    username: str = str(message.author)
    user_message: str = message.content
    channel: str = str(message.channel)

    print(f'[{channel}] {username}:       <{message.embeds}> ')


def main() -> None:
    client.run(token=TOKEN)
    bot.run(token=TOKEN)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


This code doesn't show anything, show how you get the user from the embed.

@Blitz it doesnt matter, because problem is that i cant get embed data. I get user that used SD.C Monitoring command with message.interaction.user.name, it has nothing to do with embeds. I removed unnecessary code so everyone could understand better. My problem is still appearing with given code

can i get an invite to this bot?

@Blitz i dont know how it would help with the problem, but i could invite you to my test server where this bot sits too. It outputs things things just for me in console, because it is not ready yet. Talking about discord, when you bump server it just writes how many times you bumped it, and what place you hold among other server-bumping users
But i could do it for you so that my bot outputs things about embeds in discord too

@Blitz server link: https://discord.gg/NjE9aRGe

The bot seems to be deferring the response and sending a follow-up. When it defers, the on_message is called. That's why it doesn't have embeds. After it sends a follow-up, the on_message_edit will be called.
@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before,after):
    if before.embeds != after.embeds:
        # your code here

